# update n n relation mysql codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have PostCategory table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PostCategory` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PostID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Let's assume that I have following record:

```
ID || PostID || CategoryID
===========================
1  ||   1    ||   1
2  ||   1    ||   2
3  ||   1    ||   3
4  ||   2    ||   2
```

Problem appears when I need to update Category of post with id 1
Now, if I change post categories, I get this array:

```
$categories = array(1, 2, 4);
```

and I want to update my table so it looks like this:

```
ID || PostID || CategoryID
===========================
1  ||   1    ||   1
2  ||   1    ||   2
4  ||   2    ||   2
5  ||   1    ||   4
```

As you can see I want to add one more record with CategoryID 4 and remove record with CartegoryID 3, and I want to do using one model like this:

```
$this->postCategory_model->update_post_categories($categories);
```

I just can't figure out correct structure of this model method.

Looking for some suggestions

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of 'deleting', maybe you could think about having an 'active' flag with a default value of 1 - so, at runtime, first set all flags to '0' and then 'reactivate' those that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

ok deleting the old ones faster than checking for existing then updating

```
function update_post_categories($PostID, $categories) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    //delete old cats
    $this->db->where('PostID', $PostID);
    $this->db->delete('Posts');
    //insert new ones
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $this->db->set('PostID ', $PostID);
        $this->db->set('CategoryID', $cat);
        $this->db->insert('PostCategory');
    }

    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```